# loss of Responsiveness in mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a small problem. I have to align like this-

```
                   140K  |   24k
                  Likes  |  Followers
```

In desktop view it is appearing fine in center bt in mobile view it is appearing like

```
              140k                                                       |
```

24k

I have tried sing Text-Align

```
import React from 'react'

const likeStyle={
    color:'#696969',
    borderRight: '1px solid #696969',
    paddingLeft:'45%'

}
const followStyle={
    color:'#696969'
}
export default function like(){            
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-6 col-xs-6' style={likeStyle}>
                <p style={{fontSize:'1.8em'}}>140k</p>
                <p style={{fontSize:'0.8em'}}>LIKES</p>
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-6 col-xs-6' style={followStyle}>
                <p style={{fontSize:'1.8em'}}>24k</p>
                <p style={{fontSize:'0.8em'}}>FOLLOWERS</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you need to add position: 'absolute' and paddingLeft: '45%' to followStyle as well I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to divide a screen in 2 equal parts in all the form's of devices, you can simply write `col`, learn more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width)

```
<div className='row'>
    <div className='col' style={likeStyle}>
        <p style={{fontSize:'1.8em'}}>140k</p>
        <p style={{fontSize:'0.8em'}}>LIKES</p>
    </div>
    <div className='col' style={followStyle}>
        <p style={{fontSize:'1.8em'}}>24k</p>
        <p style={{fontSize:'0.8em'}}>FOLLOWERS</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need `paddingLeft:'45%'`, instead you can use `textAlign:right`,

```
const likeStyle={
    color:'#696969',
    borderRight: '1px solid #696969',
    textAlign:'right'
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qemj7r)